# Video.play returns DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 800c000d

Tags: qt, qml, directshow

Using Qt Version 5.4.2

Error code returned : DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 800c000d

A QML file has been written with the Video QML type as below.  I have added the below in the project file (.pro)

Qt+= multimedia

Snippet of code as below in the QML file.

```
Video {
    id: video
    width : 800
    height : 600
    source : "Video.mp4"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            video.play();
        }
    }

    focus: true
    Keys.onSpacePressed: video.playbackState == MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? video.pause() : video.play()
    Keys.onLeftPressed: video.seek(video.position - 5000)
    Keys.onRightPressed: video.seek(video.position + 5000)
}
```

Any pointers regarding this error would be helpful.

Comment: A related question is unanswered in stackoverflow as below :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098203/playing-rtsp-video-in-qml-on-windows

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue, fixed it by:

changing

```
source: "file://D:/Temp/video/ccc.wmv"
```

to

```
source: "file:///D:/Temp/video/ccc.wmv"
```

as the message mentioned `doSetUrlSource` indicates may using the wrong URL.

Answer (score 3):

Have you searched through the bug tracker? I found [QTMOBILITY-1461](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTMOBILITY-1461), for example:

> The default directshow filters on Windows7 are not enough for playback of the m4a file. It is not the AAC codec problem, but no filter to identify the m4a container.
>
> The "K-Lite Codec Pack" provides "MPC - MP4 Splitter" filter which could be used to connect the m4a source to the Microsfot codec filter "Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder" to be able to play the file.
>
> Windows Media Player 12 on Windows7 uses Media Foundation instead of DirectShow to play .m4a .m2ts, .mp4, and .mov formats (for other formats it uses DirectShow filters). This explains why we could not do it with the current directshow backend implementation for QMediaPlayer without a third-party filters.
>
> We might consider adding Media Foundation support in the futrure, but for now you have to install third-party filter to have it work on Windows7.

So, installing the [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) might help.

You could also try the suggestions in [this mailing list thread](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2013-September/008783.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and reply.

Comment: @mualloc I'm not 100% certain, but you might have to mention him with "@" so that he sees your comment.

Comment: @Sudhi Could you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is qml cannot play .mp4 file.
After I try .wmv file it is working fine.